# meaning of 'go on the run'

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [a news article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/columnist/nancy-armour/2023/04/04/forget-ncaa-mens-title-game-remember-best-moments-tournament/11597529002/).

> FAU was two seconds from becoming the lowest seed to make the NCAA
> title game. Making the Owls’ run even more impressive, they’d never
> even won a tournament game before this year!
>
> “We took it to a new height,” Nick Boyd said Saturday night. “All I
> can do is smile and be appreciative of **the run we went on** and know
> next year you're going to hear it from FAU again.”

I wonder what the meaning of 'go on the run' is in the above context.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries for "run"? If so, edit your question to tell us what you found and what you're still unsure about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Go on the run' is not found in the given passage. 'Go on the run' means 'to escape from police/prison'.

In the given passage the phrase is 'the run we went on', which refers to a period of time in which a sporting person or sports team wins most or all of their games/matches.

In the present tense we would distinguish between them using 'the' vs 'a', e.g., as follows 'OJ Simpson is on the run from the police' vs. 'OJ Simpson's team is on a winning run of 30 games'. In this case the author is talking about a specific passed 'run', so he uses 'the'.